# Conditional independence iff joint factorizes

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, conditional-probability, independence, integral

I have proven that: 
$X⊥Y|Z\ {\rm iff}\ p(x,y|z)=p(x|z)p(y|z)$ for all $x,y,z$ such that $p(z)>0$.

The next question is to prove an alternative definition:
$X⊥Y|Z$ iff there exist functions $g$ and $h$ such that
$p(x,y|z)=g(x,z)h(y,z)$ for all $x,y,z$ such that $p(z)>0$.

I'm thinking that I need to integrate the function somehow...?

Comment: Is this a problem for a class? If so, please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: You have already proven one part of the iff. To prove the converse, you have indeed to integrate the second equality.

Comment: I've tried to integrate the second equality, but got stuck along the way. I could use some help with how to set up the integration procedure.

Comment: If you are given $p(x,y|z)=g(x,z)h(y,z)$, by integrating out the equality in $x$ or in $y$, you obtain the marginal conditional of $y$ or $x$ given $z$, hence deduce proportionality between $g(x,z)$ and $p(x|z)$ and similarly between $h(y,z)$ and $p(y|z)$.

Comment: Is $g(x, z)$ a pmt function for the joint distribution of $z$ and $x$? So the integral is over both $z$ and $x$? What do you mean by integrating out the equality?

Comment: I was trying to let you figure out the resolution. But since conditional integration seems an issue, I have spelled out every step in my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent given $Z$ iff $p(x,y|z)=p(x|z)p(y|z)$, all you need to prove is that, if $p(x,y|z)=g(x,z)h(y,z)$, then $p(x,y|z)=p(x|z)p(y|z)$.

Starting from the equality $p(x,y|z)=g(x,z)h(y,z)$. one can integrate both sides in x: $$
\int_\text{X}p(x,y|z)\text{d}x=\int_\text{X}g(x,z)h(y,z)\text{d}x
$$ 
This implies 
$$
p(y|z)=\int_\text{X}g(x,z)h(y,z)\text{d}x=h(y,z)\int_\text{X}g(x,z)\text{d}x
$$ 
and tells you that 
$$
h(y,z)\propto p(y|z)
$$
[where the proportionality sign is for a function of $y$, meaning that the proportionality constant can depend on $z$, i.e., $h(y,z)=\nu(z) p(y|z)$]. A symmetric argument leads to
$$
g(x,z)\propto p(x|z)
\quad\text{i.e., }
g(x,z)=\eta(z) p(x|z)
$$
Therefore,
$$
g(x,z)h(y,z)=\eta(z) p(x|z)\nu(z) p(y|z)\,,
$$
and since both sides integrate to $1$ (when integrating both in $x$ and $y$), we conclude with
$$
\eta(z) \nu(z)=1
$$
Hence,$$p(x,y|z)=p(x|z)p(y|z)$$

Comment: Could you please clarify the following:

> and since both sides integrate to 1 (when integrating both in x and y), we conclude with

$$
\eta(z)v(z)=1
$$

Comment: If I integrate both sides of$$g(x,z)h(y,z)=\eta(z) p(x|z)\nu(z) p(y|z)$$I get$$1=\int p(x,y|z)\text{d}x\text{d}y=\int g(x,z)h(y,z)\text{d}x\text{d}y=\int \eta(z) p(x|z)\nu(z) p(y|z)\text{d}x\text{d}y=\eta(z)\nu(z)\times 1$$